# Git: Switch workspaces (computers) without committing

Tags: git, workflow, git-commit, git-checkout

Is there a way to apply a diff patch or similar without doing a commit/checkout?

---

**My situation**:
I often switch between computers when working, and my commit history has a bunch of "*switching machines*" messages.

My initial guess is that this could lead to other troubles, but thought I might ask in case there is a suitable solution or workflow for this situation.

Edit - clarification: Computers are networked.

Edit - deeper thoughts: Now that I think about it, this would cause some bigger problems with the revision history by not going through Git. But perhaps there is another workflow solution I haven't thought of?

Comment: Are the machines networked in any way?

Comment: @TriskalJM Yes they are

Comment: If they're networked, having your working copy in a shared network drive seems like it would resolve the issue of a cluttered commit log.

Comment: That might actually work out for me. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Can't you `push` your changes to a *remote* repo and then when you've switched machines, just `pull` them to update your code?

Comment: @Harmelodic That's what I currently do. But I dislike all the "switching machines" commit log silly-ness.

Comment: Ah I see, in which cases either do as TriskalJM says and have you local repo in a networked drive, or change you workflow to committing smaller amounts of code, more regularly and try to finish up to a "proper" commit on the machine your working on at the time. Then once that's been committed and pushed, you can switch machines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this as a proper answer, so it can be accepted.

## Shared Network Drive

Since the machines are networked, just put your working copy on a shared network resource. This would remove the need to commit before switching workstations.

Comment: With this approach, what happens when you change to a different branch on one machine?

Comment: The working copy (which resides on the network share) would now be on the different branch. You'd need to commit or stash before doing so, but you'd have to do that regardless.

Comment: Beware of IDEs like those from JetBrains that auto-save because you would have two conflicting editors if you have them both opened and switch between them and do work, albeit different work. For this reason alone, I recommend you choose @tul's answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 10):

One of the nice things about git is that committing is separate to publishing. This lets you commit work-in-progress commits without having to publish them and having 'messy history' on record for evermore.

My suggestion would be to continue to do the commits when switching workspaces, as that gives you a solid point-in-time backup, and removes any reliance on the workspaces being networked all the time (thus enabling efficient working with a laptop for instance).

To solve the solution of the untidy history due to the 'switching workspaces' commits, I would suggest that you work on topic branches, or 'dev' branches, and when a feature is finished squash all the working commits together and then merge the newly tidied history onto the master branch.

Running `git rebase -i master` on your topic branch will let you group and squash your commits to get tidy history before merging to master and pushing to 'final history'.

Comment: This, I think, is the most versatile solution and uses git itself to solve the problem. I could keep my own working branch and use it to navigate features and workspaces alike. Thank you for this suggestion. I will definitely add this to my workflow.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer! It works perfectly and uses the power of Git, without any extra dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're networked, another option that I don't yet see mentioned here is just to **remote into one machine from the other**. Sometimes this is easier than using the full powers of git, especially you change machines unpredictably and quite often. On Linux you'd use SSH and on Windows you'd use the Remote Desktop Protocol. You might be able to use SSH on Windows via Msys2 or Windows Subsystem for Linux.

VSCode has an extension to enable remote development using SSH which might be helpful for this, as by itself, SSH works best if your git workflow is entirely text-based. If it isn't, and VSCode isn't enough, you can enable -X11 forwarding on both machines to access the graphical interface.

If you aren't on a local network, be a little careful with Windows Remote Desktop. If you have it publicly exposed to the internet via port forwarding on your router you will get pounded with brute force attacks. To avoid this you can get a router with a built-in VPN. Or maybe your situation allows you to just live with the attacks and mitigate them with super strong passwords, an obscure user name, and some good luck.